# Why the aggregate function does not give the desired result?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

Was trying to change the data type of all values in a specific field, without use of iterators.

Here tid is the field name

I tried running the code in Mongo using

```
 var ch ={"$addFields" : { "tid" : { "$convert":{"input":"$tid" , "to" : 2}}}}

 db.test.aggregate(ch);
```

Where test is my collection

Java Code :

```
BasicDBObject fieldObject = new BasicDBObject();
fieldObject.put("$convert",new BasicDBObject().append("input", 
"$tid").append("to", 2));
BasicDBObject addField = new BasicDBObject("$addFields",new 
BasicDBObject("tid",fieldObject));
System.out.println(addField);

List<BasicDBObject> options = new ArrayList<>();
options.add(addField);
details.aggregate(options);
```

When I ran the code in mongo command line, the data types are changing from Integer to String.
But no change when I run the same through java code. Is there any issue with my Java Code.

Comment: I am using java-mongo-driver 3.6.0.

Comment: .append("to",2) is used to convert the Integer to String. (As specified in the mongo manual)

Comment: You can transform the aggregation pipeline query code to Java code in the MongoDB Compass, if you have. Since you have the working command-line code you can get the correct Java code. Hope you have Compass tool; select the collection in Compass and then look for the Aggregations tab..

Comment: Here are useful links about using the Compass: [aggregation-pipeline-builder](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/aggregation-pipeline-builder/index.html) and 
[export-pipeline-to-language](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/export-pipeline-to-language/).

Comment: @prasad_ Thanks for the info.

Comment: I got what I was looking for,  BasicDBObject duplicate = new BasicDBObject();
        duplicate.put("$out","test"); details.aggregate(options).toCollection; Does the trick

Comment: @prasad_ will look into Compass